# How to average multiple table files with different x and y values

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I got some table files containing the same measuring result but due to little differences the data points got different *x* and *y* values. But I need an average across all six files. Here are two (shortened) example files:

```
# file1.dat
  9.840000000000000E+00  1.680000000000000E+02
  9.840071206052514E+00  1.730000000000000E+02
  9.840142412105029E+00  1.630000000000000E+02
  9.840213618157543E+00  1.730000000000000E+02
  9.840284824210057E+00  1.690000000000000E+02
  9.840356030262573E+00  1.720000000000000E+02
  9.840427236315087E+00  1.660000000000000E+02
  9.840498442367601E+00  1.750000000000000E+02
  9.840569648420116E+00  1.650000000000000E+02
  9.840640854472630E+00  1.720000000000000E+02
```

```
# file2.dat
  9.840000000000000E+00  1.720000000000000E+02
  9.840071016422547E+00  1.760000000000000E+02
  9.840142032845096E+00  1.610000000000000E+02
  9.840213049267643E+00  1.530000000000000E+02
  9.840284065690192E+00  1.590000000000000E+02
  9.840355082112739E+00  1.590000000000000E+02
  9.840426098535286E+00  1.690000000000000E+02
  9.840497114957834E+00  1.790000000000000E+02
  9.840568131380381E+00  1.680000000000000E+02
  9.840639147802928E+00  1.620000000000000E+02
```

[and four more similar files …]

If I plot them all with `gnuplot` but each table as an own curve I get this
[image: gnuplot]

But I need a single curve showing the average of all six tables.

I tried `join` but I get an empty file as the result and I Guess it won’t work because the first column (*x* values) doesn’t contain the same values in each file. Trying to do the summation in `gnuplot` with `plot data1 u 1:2 + data2 u 1:2` fails too.

I found [merging multiple data files to plot in a single graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7218201/1018250) but it doesn’t help to only merge the files.

---

I’m using Mac OS X but have access to an Ubuntu to, so if there are any tool to do that …

---

The new ouptut of the script

```
> AVDEBUG=1 octave -qf avfiles.m messung3.dat messung4.dat
warning: ================
warning: processing file: messung3.dat
warning: size of the matrix in the file: 2248      3
warning: min(x): 0.000000e+00
warning: max(x): 0.000000e+00
warning: min(y): 9.840000e+00
warning: max(y): 1.000000e+01
warning: ================
warning: processing file: messung4.dat
warning: size of the matrix in the file: 2254      3
warning: min(x): 0.000000e+00
warning: max(x): 0.000000e+00
warning: min(y): 9.840000e+00
warning: max(y): 1.000000e+01
warning: yp is undefined at 2248 points
```

If you like you can download my data files from [here (tweh.de/texsx/data-files-avarage.zip)](http://tweh.de/texsx/data-files-avarage.zip). The avarage should be made out of all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy in [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). Create file `avfiles.m`. Usage:

```
octave -qf avfiles.m file1.dat file2.dat
```

`octave -q --eval "test avfiles"` creates files with test data `aux_file[0-9]`.

**avfiles.m:**

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
# Average y values in several files
# Usage:
# octave -qf avfiles.m aux_file0 aux_file1 aux_ file2

if isempty(getenv("AVDEBUG"))
  warning ("off", "avfiles")
endif

setenv("LC_NUMERIC", "C"); 

arg_list = argv ();
for k = 1:nargin
  fname = arg_list{k};
    warning ("avfiles", "================");
    warning ("avfiles", "processing file: %s", fname);
    data = dlmread(fname);
    warning ("avfiles", "size of the matrix in the file: %s", num2str(size(data)));
    x = data(:, 1);
    y = data(:, 2);
    warning ("avfiles", "min(x): %e", min(x));
    warning ("avfiles", "max(x): %e", max(x));
    warning ("avfiles", "min(y): %e", min(y));
    warning ("avfiles", "max(y): %e", max(y));
    [x, idx] = sort(x);
    y = y(idx);
    if k==1
      % use x values from the first file
      xp = x; yp = y;
    else
      yp = 1/k * ( (k-1)*yp + interp1(x, y, xp) );
      warning ("avfiles", "yp is undefined at %d points", sum(isnan(yp)));
    endif
endfor

idx = !isnan(yp);
dlmwrite("/dev/stdout", [xp(idx), yp(idx)], ' ');

%!test
%! n = 100;
%! for k=0:9
%!   x = unifrnd(0, 2*pi, n, 1);
%!   y = sin(x) + 0.05*stdnormal_rnd(n, 1);
%!   dlmwrite(sprintf("aux_file%i", k), [x y], " ");
%! end
%! system("octave -qf avfiles.m aux_file[0-9] > aux_out");
%! data = dlmread("aux_out");
%! x = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2);
%! assert(sin(x), y, 0.08);
```

Run `AVDEBUG=1 octave -qf avfiles.m file1.dat file2.dat` to get tracing. With you example files I get:

```
warning: ================
warning: processing file: file1.dat
warning: size of the matrix in the file: 10    2
warning: min(x): 9.840000e+00
warning: max(x): 9.840639e+00
warning: min(y): 1.530000e+02
warning: max(y): 1.790000e+02
warning: ================
warning: processing file: file2.dat
warning: size of the matrix in the file: 10    2
warning: min(x): 9.840000e+00
warning: max(x): 9.840641e+00
warning: min(y): 1.630000e+02
warning: max(y): 1.750000e+02
warning: yp is undefined at 0 points
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’ll try it as soon as I can install `octave` :-)

Comment: Hm … I installed `octave` but when I call the script I get the message `error: Invalid call to dlmwrite.  Correct usage is:`

Comment: @Tobi What happens if you try `octave -q --eval "test avfiles"`? Which version of octave you have (`octave -v`)? I have tested with 3.6.2 and 3.6.0.

Comment: @Tobi Try to change `dlmwrite(stdout(), [xp(idx), yp(idx)], ' ')` to `dlmwrite(stdout, [xp(idx), yp(idx)], ' ')`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t work even if I change the line. I added the full error code to my original question above …

Comment: Now the script runs without erros but where do I find the resulting data file? :-)

Comment: `octave -qf avfiles.m file1.dat file2.dat > output.dat` or `plot "<octave -qf avfiles.m file1.dat file2.dat"` should work in gnuplot shell.

Comment: Hm … it works with the test files but not with my original files … do you have any idea why? When using my original files the resulting file is empty.

Comment: @Tobi I add tracing to the script. Is you output different from what I wrote in the answerer (run `AVDEBUG=1 octave -qf avfiles.m file1.dat file2.dat`)?

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn’t … I’ll add my output to the question …

Comment: From you output: `warning: size of the matrix in the file: 2248      3`. Octave thinks there are 3 columns in the file. I think it is a problem with locale. I've added `setenv("LC_NUMERIC", "C");` to the script.

Comment: That doesn’t help but I deleted the spaces at the beginning of all lines an now it works fine :-) Thank you very much!